# Can I rename tmux tabs to hostnames and commands?

Tags: tmux

I'd like my tmux tabs to display the hostname of the machine (the guest machine if I'm SSHed) and the currently running command on that machine. Is that possible? Thus, if I have machines named "Home" (host machine) "Hemingway" (remote) and "Fitzgerald" (remote), I'd like my tabs to look like this:

```
Home: bash   Hemingway: top   Fitzgerald: less
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can help you. But I've created, just now [a script](https://github.com/sensorario/startmux) with the purpose to customize my windows. In customisation are included also window names.